# drag and drop execution not working in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

When I drop a zip file onto nodewebkit binary file (execution bit is set) it won't launch the application. I have to use terminal and run it like

```
./nw ./myapp.zip
```

Is there a way to enable drag and drop application  launching in nautilus?